# ntp port was blocked, how to sync time

Tags: linux, debian, ntp

### Description

I am currently learning related knowledge in my study. When I use Debian operating system on my Raspberry PI, I find that the system time is not synchronized with the real time.

### Errors

1. The error message is as follows.

```
 Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses not yet valid certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 101.6.15.130 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses not yet valid certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 101.6.15.130 443]
```

NTP has been configured (maybe I didn't? But I have carefully configured it according to the documentation, if possible, you can briefly describe the configuration process.) after many times, I still can't figure out the problem.

### ntp.conf files

2. My `ntp.conf` as follows:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

# Leap seconds definition provided by tzdata
leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list

# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable


# You do need to talk to an NTP server or two (or three).
#server ntp.your-provider.example
server ntp.aliyun.com iburst minpoll 4 maxpoll 10

# pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will
# pick a different set every time it starts up.  Please consider joining the
# pool: <http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html>
pool 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst


# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Needed for adding pool entries
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery
restrict ntp.aliyun.com nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust


# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
#broadcastclient
root@rpi4-20210823:~#
```

3. somethings about my ntp

```
root@rpi4-20210823:~# date
Wed Jul 14 03:05:09 CST 2021
root@rpi4-20210823:~# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 1.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 2.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 3.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 203.107.6.88    .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

4. My OS as follows

```
root@rpi4-20210823:~# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 11 \n \l

root@rpi4-20210823:~# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

root@rpi4-20210823:~# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: rpi4-20210823
         Icon name: computer
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
            Kernel: Linux 5.10.0-8-arm64
      Architecture: arm64
```

**I really want to know how to solve this problem, Thanks very much:)**
If you have any questions, please leave a message and communicate with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you posted seems to be unrelated to your issue, as it looks like an apt-get error.
Where have you extracted it from?

That being said, are you able to manually sync time with ntpdate?
You can try doing something like this:

```
# apt install ntpdate
# ntpdate -v ntp.on.br
```

This will show clearly if you have some network problem/restriction preventing you to reach your NTP servers.

Comment: I typed the command as you suggested. And I received this 
`ntpdate[1396]: ntpdate 4.2.8p12@1.3728-o (1)` and `ntpdate[1396]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting`

Comment: Since I am from a University in China, I think the 123 port may be prohibited by the network server of the school. So I wanted to find some other way to synchronize time like WSL

Comment: Make sure you stop your ntpd daemon before attempting to manually sync with ntpdate: ```sudo systemctl stop ntpd``` should do it.

Comment: If UDP port 123 is forbidden by your local network, I am afraid there's not much to be done. It is possible however that your local network provides an internal NTP server you can use. You can either ask your admin or attempt to see if any NTP servers were advertised by your internal DHCP server. You could then either snoop a DHCP request (with wireshark) or attempt to use chrony (with network manager, used instead of ntpd) which reports NTP server advertised by DHCP: ```chronyc sources```

Comment: I finally solved the problem by asking my network admin for the NTP address, but I still wondered how WSL synchronizes time.

Comment: I think either your network does allow access to time.windows.com, or some internal ntp server is advertised with your DHCP request, and Windows will use this by default.

Comment: Thinks sir. Best wish!